# Programmatically extend/customize the windows logon prompt

Tags: windows

Is the windows (XP, Vista, 7) logon box extensible ? Is there an "logon box" analog to  windows shell extensions ?

As a made up example, I have a windows host with one shared account used by my team. I want my team members to be able to login to the host desktop by solving a captcha. I would like to modify the logon box to do this (instead of say, having an autologon and then being shown a fullscreen captcha program)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To customize the logon window, you have to create a [Credential Provider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb648647%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) in Vista/7, and a [GINA dll](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa378750%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) in XP.